# How I can add an ul li list element using an element of WebControls in VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I'm working in an old project creating a User Control to add code that will change as I need.
I'd like to add a list element but I only found the property to create list type of `<select>` using `<asp:ListBox`, but this is not that I'm looking for

Do you know how generate a `<ul><li>` elements using Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls? or at least modify its CssClass properties since my VB code. It'd be amazing if I can use a loop to generate the list items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a `BulletedList` in your `WebForm.aspx`:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>
```

Then in your `WebForm.aspx.vb` you can add items:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 3
    BulletedList1.Items.Add("item" & i)
Next
```

If you inspect your page in a web browser you will see these are equivalent to `<ul><li>` HTML tags.

Comment: Yes, this is just I was looking for. Thanks a lot (and thanks for the correction, I also need to improve my English XD)

Comment: Glad I could help. English is my only language and I still need to improve it.